# Decipher what language or syntax this is

Tags: programming-languages

We are trying to decipher some rule syntax and are unsure of its origin.

Here is an example:

```
(CARS->TYPE='C').and.(CARS->CD_CODE<>'').and.('|'+INVOICE->TYPE+'|'$'|AAA|').and.('|'+SUBSTR(INVOICE->TYPE,1,2)+'|'$'|11|')
```

Specifically we are trying to understand `|` and `$`. Can anyone let me know if they have seen similar and elude to the source language or the correct interpretation of the `|` and `$`?

Comment: There were a lot of languages back in the olden days with syntax similar to that.  It is FORTRANish, but more likely something else.

Comment: (Looks kinda database-ish.  But not COBOL and certainly not RPG.  Could be some other report generator language, though.)

Comment: Honestly, you should probably give the domain, which might help point to the meanings of the operators.  It could be anything from ancient to Coq with custom infix operators.

Comment: so we think Answer 1 is almost 100% but one final peice is,

Comment: so we think Answer 1 is almost 100% but one final piece is, ('|'+SUBSTR(INVOICE->TYPE,1,2)+'|'$'|11|') - Is it true in this part that the rule indicates that $ = Contains or Starts With or Like

some info about the INVOICE type - it is now known is it always a 3 digit number, each of the numbers 1-9 specify part of an invoice type. So a 112 = Dealer Invoice with some details while a 219, or 431 equal something completely different. So our assumption to be proven is - This rule should be stating IF Invoice code is starting with 11x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From it's syntax we can tell it is a "modern" language. Remember "*modern*" alright ;)

```
substr
.and. 
->
```

are pretty modern, in compare with cobol and assembling language.

> (CARS->TYPE='C').and.(CARS->CD_CODE<>'').and.('|'+INVOICE->TYPE+'|'$'|AAA|').and.('|'+SUBSTR(INVOICE->TYPE,1,2)+'|'$'|11|')

A pseudo code would be something as:

```
(if car type is 'C'
and
if car cd_code is not empty
and
if invoice type is 'AAA'
and
if invoice type first 2 letters are '11')
then return true
```

My guess about using $ would be:

```
= and <> are only when compare against a character
$ when compare array of character, i.e. strings.
```

(I don't know what the output would be, as it compares the entire invoice type with AAA and even with the first two letters as 11. Maybe you have edited the code before submitting it?)

**Fortran 90** would be a guess, but even **DBase III** maybe.

DBase link:
http://lynnbob.com/bob/articles/DBASEIIIPlusLevel2.htm

Fortran link:
http://www.ews.uiuc.edu/~mrgates2/docs/fortran.html

For DBASE regarding the pipes...

*If you pass parameters, they must be delimited by | | (pipes). The pipes, ||, are required even if no parameters are passed. If you pass parameters, they are delimited within the ||.*

Answer (score 0):

It's not BASIC, Pascal, C, Java, perl, Python, COBOL, or FORTRAN, that much I can tell you from experience with those languages. It might be helpful to mention what rules engine you're using.

The operation being performed looks a lot like a match operation.

'|' looks like a string literal for the pipe character | , and given the context, it's probably being used as a separator in a flat-file format database sort of like CSV. For example, the plaintext would probably be something like |INVOICETYPE|something|AAA|

Can't help you with the $ operator, though. That could be a variable substitution or a match-anything operation or even a concatenator.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: *Fortran.*

It's a rather complex language now. I don't believe it has a `->` operator but it does seem to have `=>`.  Perhaps that's a vendor-extension in your snippet.

The pro-Fortran evidence is the `.and.` operator.

Comment: Wouldn't FORTRAN use `/=` or `.ne.`instead of `<>`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a FORTRAN-ish language. The `->` is not an standard operator though. The `|` is just a string (doesn't look like an operator), but the `$` certainly looks like an operator, maybe something for specifying string formatting? inferring this cform the fact that it always appears between groups of strings.